# How can I pack and wrap eyeglasses protectively for shipping?

Tags: eyeglasses

As COVID-19 has forfended non-essential travelling, I must ship these eyeglasses rather than carry them with me in person on the plane.

1. I'll definitely buy insurance for the eyeglasses.
2. If the manufacturer's case is big enough, I'll [bubble-wrap](https://youtu.be/Oj0Q9i_64q8?t=83) the frame first. Then I'll place the eyeglasses in the manufactuer's case and bubble-wrap the case too. Then I'll [place it in a small box](https://old.reddit.com/r/Ebay/comments/b0r7xp/cheapest_way_to_ship_sunglasses/eigmgnk/). Finally I'll place the smaller box inside a bigger box for more protection.
3. But what if the manufacturer's case can fit only the eyeglass itself, and is too small  to fit eyeglass with bubble wrap?
4. How else can I protect these eyeglasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question appears to be

> But what if the manufacturer's case can fit only the eyeglass itself, and is too small to fit eyeglass with bubble wrap?

If the bubblewrap is too thick, then use something thinner to protect the glasses. They are usually supplied with a small soft cloth inside the case. Wrap the glasses with that, and/or a larger piece of soft cloth. Wrap as many layers as there is room for, to stop them moving freely inside the case.

The case should be the hard shell type, not a soft pouch, to protect the glasses. It is a good idea to use bubble wrap outside that, for further cushioning.

Comment: +1 for the hard shell glasses case. That's a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You have already taken every reasonable precaution to ship the eyeglasses safely and securely.

Where there is some space you wish to fill, small pieces of loosely-crumpled paper can be used to absorb shock. The crumpled paper isn't messy as styrofoam plastic peanut dust or lint from cloth.

Good luck.